# crystal reports-get data on two separate pages

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a crystal report ,into which I am pulling data from the database.

The data is pulled and displayed perfectly, but I want it to be displayed on two separate pages with different page headers.

Ex

```
name loginid         delivery  asp/net     com   
ud   ud@gmail.com     yes      asp         com
```

currently these fields are displayed on one page but i want it like as follows:

```
page 1   
name    loginod         delivery  
ud      ud@gmail.com     yes

page 2  
asp/net    com  
asp        com
```

Can any1 help?

Answer (score 0):

- Insert a second `details` section
- Position fields as desired
- Add this formula to `details A` conditional-suppression formula:

  ```
  // suppress section when page number is even (e.g. 2,4,6,...)
  Remainder(RecordNumber,2)=0
  ```
- Add this formula to `details B` conditional-suppression formula:

  ```
  // suppress section when page number is odd (e.g. 1,3,5,...)
  Remainder(RecordNumber,2)<>0
  ```